# comparison between return images using file_exists() or glob() php

Tags: php

I'm currently working with images this way:

**FIRST APPROACH**

This is a direct linking between the image and its database token: It returns the image. this approach doesnt care if the image exists or not.

```
 $token = "abc";

  echo "<img src='images/$token/image.jpg' />";
```

I want to know if it would be better this another way:

**SECOND APPROACH**

```
 $token="abc";

 $image_url="images/$token/image.jpg";

 if(file_exists($image_url)){

 echo "<img src='$image_url' />
 }else{

  echo "<img src='icons/no-image.png' />

  }
```

or this another way

**THIRD APPPROACH**

```
 $token = "abc";

$files = glob("images/$token/".'/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

  foreach($files as $file) {
           echo "<img src='$file' />
   }
```

I'm currently using the first approach, which you would be more recommendable and why?

Comment: Only 1 is putting out the `no-image.png`.. do you want that when there is no image available?

Comment: These codes aren't really comparable, they both do pretty different things.

Comment: What would be a better approach then? mixing up `file_exists()` with `glob()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glob` is looking for 3 file formats. The `file_exists` is only looking for the requested file. The `file_exists` will take less resources to process (although probably not noticeable). The `<img` call with display a broken image on the page if it doesn't exist.

I'd go with the `file_exists`, unless the formats vary, then you'll need to go with the `glob`.

Here's a shortened `file_exists` version:

```
$image_url="images/$token/image.jpg";
$image_output = file_exists($image_url) ? "<img src='$image_url' />" : "<img src='icons/no-image.png' />";
echo $image_output;
```

Comment: ok thank you. I havra better undestanding now. But one question. does `glob` takes more resources?

Comment: @Joe Yes, because you are using a pattern so it has to evaluate that, then find matches.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion second approach is good if you want to display **only one** image.
Moreover you have the case if token does not exists.

The third is also good if  you wanna display one or more images **BUT** you forgot to check if **$files** is empty.

So the right solution depends on your needs.

Do i answer your question?

Comment: the tokein  will always exists. and a file named as token. How it would be if I would like to mix `file_exists()` with `glob()`

Comment: if glob returns a filename, this file exists so it's useless to use both!

Comment: so if using glob() in what moment would I use `no-image.png` then?

Comment: "the tokein will always exists. and a file named as token." so do you always have image or not?

Comment: not always. Sometimes. It depends in errors at uploading the images via php script

Comment: so you ve to check if `globe` returns files or not